# Question marks at the end of statements

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis, question-mark

Do either or both of the two sentences below require a question mark?

> - Just confirming that we are still on tomorrow for our 3 pm meeting with S&P management**?**
> - I am free to chat this evening as well, if that works better for you**?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to [ell.se]

Comment: Where has the question mark come from? Why do you think it's needed?

Answer (score 3):

No, those do not need question marks. They are indirect questions, and as such, do not require a question mark.

From *The Grammar Bible* by Michael Strumpf (p. 536):

> The indirect question asks a question in a declarative manner. The difference between the direct and indirect quesionts will be subtle.
>
> DIRECT: What kind of pasta is that?
>
> INDIRECT: She asked what kind of pasta that is.
>
> The direct question always ends with a question mark.

Your examples should be written:

Just confirming that we are still on tomorrow for our 3 pm meeting with S&P management.

I am free to chat this evening as well, if that works better for you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds trite to say so, but for a question mark to be appropriate you have to actually ask a question. For your examples to be questions, you would have to re-write them, for example:

Are we still on tomorrow for our 3 pm meeting with S&P management? I need to confirm it today.

I am free to chat this evening as well. Does that work better for you?